# Swap Partition: What to do with two different swaps, one of them encrypted?

Tags: swap

I installed Ubuntu for the first time a few months back, and I have recently begun to really try and learn how my system works. So today I have been reading about Swap Partitions and so I have been looking at what my setting where. I have read that its good to have no more than 2X your RAM in swap space.

So when I started to look at my Disks it said I had about 6GB in swap, but when I used Gparted it said my partition was "unknown" and unable to detect. So I found a tutorial online which walked me through setting up a Partition File and the end result was that I created a 12 GB Partition File.

Shortly after I finished I then read that Gparted cannot read Swap Partitions that are encrypted, thus my original swap Partition was not necessarily corrupted but just unreadable due to encryption.

So if you are in my shoes with 6 GB of Swap Partition (from install) and a newly created 12 GB swap file what would you do? I feel one of these Swaps needs to be deleted or both altered. Thanks for the help everybody!!

Comment: Why not just deleting one and keeping the other? I don't know whether you want/need swap encryption, but in general it is easier without...

Answer (score 0):

There is no point in having more than your RAM in swap. By the time you have that much data stored there, you would have died of old age waiting for the incredibly slow hard drive to be used as RAM. The *only* reason you would want more than a few gigabytes is for Hibernation, which is disabled by default because of bugs. I would delete the 12 GB file, as you would need to edit `/etc/fstab` and set the new partition as swap. Backup your data first. The encryption of swap I have not heard of. Unless you are planning on Hibernating (which requires some small configuration, etc.) then there is **no point** in having more than 6GB of swap (with 6GB of ram).